# How to access the current element property name of the called function

Tags: javascript, wrapper, object-properties

For logging purpose, I've created a wrapper function for an element functions properties.
The wrapper function is above:

```
functionsWrapper: function () {
    for (i = 0, args = new Array(arguments.length); i < arguments.length; i++) {
        args[i] = arguments[i];
    }

    console.log('call for ' + arguments.callee.name + ' with params ' + argumantsLog(args));

    return this['original' + arguments.callee.name].apply(this, args);
}
```

And then I'm using this code to wrap the element function:

```
logFunctionsCalls: function (element) {
    if (!element)
        return;

    if (element.children && element.children.length)
        for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++)
            logFunctionsCalls(element.children[i]);

    if (!element.functionsLogged) {
        element.functionsLogged = true;

        for (var property in element) {
            if (typeof element[property] != 'function')
                continue;

            element['original' + property] = element[property];
            element[property] = functionsWrapper;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `arguments.callee` contains the `functionsWrapper` code without the property name of the called function.

Comment: `arguments.callee.name`? That's one deprecated and one non-standard property, and neither will actually help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same `functionWrapper` everywhere - there's no way to find out as which property it was called. Instead, created different wrappers and keep the original in closure.

```
for (var p in element) (function(property) {
    if (typeof element[property] != 'function')
        return;

    var original = element[property];
    element[property] = function wrapped() {
        console.log('call for ' + property + ' with params ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments));
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}(p));
```

Comment: I've used something similar before the current version, but I must change it because for some reason, the `arguments` object is pointed to irrelevant arguments from other functions call.

Comment: What do you mean by "*pointed to irrelevant arguments from other functions call*"? Please provide some reproducible code example.

Comment: For example, I'm getting "src", "http://www.google.com/" that is clearly the passed arguments for `setAttribute` at the function `appendChild`

Comment: Please show us how you are calling those functions. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39264210/edit) to include the code.

Comment: I don't know why, but my code was pretty the same as yours except the using of inline function, but your code work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Well yes, [that IIFE is very important for the closure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572).